# (PHP) Displaying images from dynamic directories

Tags: php, xml, image, xhtml

On one server, I successfully write the image as follows:

```
$structure = "./images/$root->City/$root->ZipCode/$root->StreetDirection $root->StreetName/";

file_put_contents("./$structure/$root->StreetNumber $root->StreetDirection $root->StreetName $root->StreetSuffix $root->City $root->ZipCode-{$number}.jpeg", $photo['Data']);
```

Then I try to retrieve and display same image same location with the following, nothing happens (broken image link):

```
$structure = "../images/$City_R/$Zip_Code_R/$StreetDirection $StreetName $StreetSuffix/$StreetNumber $StreetDirection $StreetName $StreetSuffix $City_R $Zip_Code_R-1";
$img = '<img src="'.$structure.'.jpeg" style="border-style:solid; border-width:10px; border-color:#fff; width=500px; id=Main_Image;"><br/>';

echo '$img';
```

In testing, it only seems to pull when name is greatly simplified and no dynamic directories specified..., in fact, it ignores directories all together...

Comment: probably you are using a path, whereas you need a url for the img src

Comment: echoing '$img' ? meh ? am I the only one to find that amusing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not build the src attribute in this way. I would build it outside the quotes, because dealing with spaces inside of quotes while inserting variable values can get unnecessarily complicated.
Simply use the concatenation operator outside of the string:

```
$structure = "../images/" . $City_R . "/" . $Zip_Code_R . "/" . $StreetDirection . $StreetName . $StreetSuffix . "/" . $StreetNumber . $StreetDirection . $StreetName . $StreetSuffix . $City_R . $Zip_Code_R-1;

//etc...
```

Note you need to be using a URL for the image source, and you're using a path. Your src attribute ideally will start with "http://www.example.com/"

And rather than using spaces in the filenames, use dashes which has the added benefit in that it is much better for SEO as well :)